# Showing an equation with double sum of exponential expression and squared sine expression

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

I assume that the following equation is true:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\ell=-k}^k \exp(i \ell x) = \left( \frac{\sin\left( -\frac{n+1}{2}x \right)}{ \sin\left( -\frac{x}{2} \right)} \right)^2$$

This would be the missing piece for an exercise where I need to show a more complicated equation involving Fourier polynomials.

However, I have trouble showing the above equation. On the left side of the equation, I have trouble dealing with the sums of the exponential expression, for which there is no general law (as far as I know). On the right side of the equation, I have trouble dealing with the square and the fraction of the sine expressions.

Does anyone have an idea of how to deal with this equation?

Comment: The sum is the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) multiplied by $n+1$, you can find a proof in the link.

Answer (score 0):

One way is translating the index $\ell$ to make it start at zero and then use the (partial) geometric series twice, i.e.
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\ell=-k}^k e^{i\ell x}
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\ell=0}^{2k} e^{i(\ell-k)x} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-ikx} \frac{1-e^{i(2k+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{1-e^{ix}} \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-ikx} - \frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}} \sum_{k=0}^n e^{ikx} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{1-e^{ix}} \frac{1-e^{-i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{-ix}} - \frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}} \frac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}  \\
\end{array}
$$
and you will get the wanted result after some (annoying) algebraic cleaning. Alternatively, you can argue that $e^{ikx} + e^{-ikx} = 2\cos(kx)$, hence
$$
\sum_{\ell=-k}^k e^{i\ell x} = 1 + 2\sum_{\ell=1}^k \cos(\ell x) = \frac{\sin((k+\frac{1}{2})x)}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})},
$$
and then make usage of $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ for $\alpha = \frac{nx}{2}$ and $\beta = \frac{x}{2}$, in order to get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\sin((k+\frac{1}{2})x)}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})} = \cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sum_{k=0}^n \sin\left(\frac{kx}{2}\right) + \sum_{k=0}^n \cos\left(\frac{kx}{2}\right)
$$
Those two last summations are known as [Lagrange trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange%27s_trigonometric_identities). And I let you finish.